# Parallel lines separator in Konva

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to draw a separator with 2 lines for my road. I already tried to make it with just 2 parallels lines, but when I made my road curve, it doesn't look very good. Like this:

Small curve:

[image]

Big curve:

[image]

Because of it now I am just drawing one line with white background behind the line with black background. But sometimes my main road is not black. How can I make space between these lines transparent?

Examples:

Normal work:

[image]

Work with road with different background:

[image]

You can drag separator in the example below

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
var line = new Konva.Line({
    points: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    strokeWidth: 100,
    stroke: 'black',
    draggable: true,

});

var line_2 = new Konva.Line({
    points: [400, 100, 500, 200],
    strokeWidth: 100,
    stroke: 'red',
    draggable: true,
});
const group_sep = new Konva.Group({
    draggable: true,
});
var sep_1 = new Konva.Line({
    points: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    strokeWidth: 20,
    stroke: 'green',
});

var sep_2 = new Konva.Line({
    points: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    strokeWidth: 10,
    stroke: '#000000',

});

group_sep.add(sep_1);
group_sep.add(sep_2);
layer.add(line);
layer.add(line_2);
layer.add(group_sep);
stage.add(layer);
layer.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.16/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [blend mode](https://konvajs.org/docs/styling/Blend_Mode.html) via `globalCompositeOperation` to "cut" one line from another.

```js
const group_sep = new Konva.Group({
    draggable: true,
});
var sep_1 = new Konva.Line({
    points: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    strokeWidth: 20,
    stroke: 'green',
});

// destination-out will cut line from previous drawings
var sep_2 = new Konva.Line({
    points: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    strokeWidth: 10,
    stroke: '#000000',
    globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-out'
});
```

But you should know that `destination-out` will cut your line from ALL previous drawings on the canvas. It means it may cut the background too. To fix the issues you can move your group with the lines into another `Konva.Layer` or just cache the group:

```js
group_sep.cache();
```

**Note: remember to recache to group every time you change the lines.**

Demo: https://jsbin.com/ravodomigi/3/edit?html,js,output